# How can I see Debug.Log output in MonoDevelop Unity when connected to a device?

Tags: debugging, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

When debugging in Unity Editor I can see the Debug.Log() output in the Console, which is great. However, when connecting MonoDevelop to a device I don't know where to find this output. It is not in the "Application Output" window. Breakpoints, variables, stack - all works fine. Is there a way to see the debug output in MonoDevelop?

Is there anything better then this answer suggests? [Debug/Trace output in MonoDevelop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680998/debug-trace-output-in-monodevelop)

Comment: Added solution, see below started with "Solved!..."

Answer (score 9):

1) Enable "USB debugging" on your device and connect the device to your development machine via USB cable. Ensure your device is on the same subnet mask and gateway as your development machine. Also, make sure there are no other active network connections on the device (i.e. disable data access over mobile/cellular network).

2) On your development machine, open up your terminal/cmd and navigate to the location of the ADB. You can find the ADB tool in /platform-tools/

3) Restart host ADB in TCP/IP mode with the following command:
adb tcpip 5555

This should produce the following output:
restarting in TCP mode port: 5555

This will have enabled ADB over TCP/IP using port 5555. If port 5555 is unavailable, you should use a different port.
(See http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html)

4) Find out the IP address of your Android device (Settings -> About -> Status) and input the following command:
adb connect DEVICEIPADDRESS
(DEVICEIPADDRESS is the actual IP address of your Android device)

This should produce the following output:
connected to DEVICEIPADDRESS:5555

5) Ensure that your device is recognised by inputting the following command:
adb devices

This should produce the following output:
List of devices attached
DEVICEIPADDRESS:5555 device

6) Build and run your Unity application to the device. Ensure you build your application with Development Build flag enabled and Script Debugging turned on.

7) The device no longer needs to be connected to your development machine via USB.

8) Finally, while the application is running on your device, open your script in MonoDevelop, add a breakpoint, select "Run" -> "Attach to Process" and select your device from the list. (Note that it might take a few seconds for the device to appear in the list. It may not appear in the list if the application is not running or if the device's display goes to sleep).

For some more details and for troubleshooting, see the Wireless Usage section in the Android developers guide for the ADB: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#wireless

NB:
The device sends multicast messages and the editor and MonoDevelop subscribe/listen for them. For this to work, your network will need to be setup correctly for Multicasting.

Taken From [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/attaching-monodevelop-debugger-to-an-android-device.245814/)

There are other ways also to debug your application in terminal

******************* **On MacOS** ***************************

Start Terminal from launchpad

**First Method**

1. Turn USB Debugging on, on your android device
2. Connect the android device through usb cable
3. Go to “platform-tools” folder in Adroid sdk folder by using “cd”
   command
4. Connect the android device through usb cable
5. type “adb devices” in terminal it will print the list of devices
   attached
6. type “adb logcat -s Unity ActivityManager PackageManager dalvikvm
   DEBUG”   to see logcat of only unity related stuffs

**Second Method**

creating an environment variable to access ADB directly

1. Go to your home directory by typing “cd ~”
2. Type touch .profile this will create a hidden file named profile
3. Type open -e .profile this will open the file you just created in
   TextEdit
4. In the file, type export
   PATH=${PATH}:/AndroidSdkPath/android-sdk-mac_86/platform-tools
5. Save file, close TextEdit, Quit Terminal, and Relaunch Terminal
6. Turn USB Debugging on, on your android device
7. Connect the android device through usb cable
8. type “adb devices” in terminal it will print the list of devices
   attached
9. type “adb logcat -s Unity ActivityManager PackageManager dalvikvm
   DEBUG”  to see logcat of only unity related stuffs

Now you can start your app/game on the target device and Terminal will log all the activities of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

1. Install "Visual Studio Community 2015" - Free to use
2. Install "VS tools for Unity" https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/unitytools-vs.aspx - Free!
3. Add Package in Unity as explained https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn940025.aspx
4. Run, attach the debugger and look into the "Error List" window - Log message will appear there as "Messages".

[image]

Should the above does not work, check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn940025.aspx , in particular: "Took a while but finally found a very simple thing that I was not aware of - being a newbie - There is a filter button on the error list, which didn't look like it was clickable, so I clicked that and messages are now coming through, who knew?"

Comment: This work OK attaching to the Unity running, but still have issues seeing messages from the app on a device